# Copy the file from another user to my home directory using shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have file names with there absolute path in one input.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
index=0
while read line ; do
myarray[$index]="$line"
index=$(($index+1))
done < input.txt
su - anotheruser <<EOF
for e in "${myarray[@]}"
do
 cp $e /home/myhomedirectory 
done
EOF
```

---

Error:
standard in must be a tty

How can we achieve the above scenario ???

Answer (score 1):

A nice xargs one liner:

```
su -c "xargs -IFILE cp 'FILE' /home/myhomedirectory/ < input.txt" anotheruser
```

Tested with echo...

```
$ cat input.txt
x/y/z
a/b/c
$ su -c "xargs -IFILE echo cp 'FILE' /home/myhomedirectory/ < input.txt" $user
Password: 
cp x/y/z /home/myhomedirectory/
cp a/b/c /home/myhomedirectory/
$
```

Note that to use the "su -c command - user" form (with "-" before user to provide login environment) a fully qualified path for the input.txt file is needed.

Comment: dzdo su -c "xargs -IFILE echo cp 'FILE' /home/myhomedircetory/ < input.txt" anotheruser